# External file and jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn web developing and how to became a front end software developer.

So far I learnt HTML, CSS following many courses and one of them started to introduce jquery.

Unfortunately I don't know why but if I use `<script> code </script>` inside the html file everything works, but if I write the code in a different page as external link nothing works.

I put the jquery CDN first and my file in second at the bottom of the file just before the closer body but nothing works it keep giving me errors

> (ERROR: '$' is not defined. [no-undef]$(function()
>
> 2ERROR: Unexpected console statement.
>   [no-console]console.log("ready!");3
>
> ERROR: 'console' is not defined. [no-undef]console.log("ready!");)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javacript" src="Resources/jquery/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.4/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

**this is what I am trying to run:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
    })
})
```

Thx guys for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `<script type="text/javacript" src="Resources/jquery/script.js"></script>` you typed `type="text/javacript"` (javascript without 's'), and the correct form is `type="text/javascript"`.  for that reason the external file fails

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').click(function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Click Me</h1>
```

Comment: OMG I did not notice before ahahahah Thank you very much Carlos